# Swap an image when selecting dark mode

Tags: javascript, css, image, themes, mode

I am looking to incorporate a dark mode switch and I need it to switch to an image when doing so but can't figure it out.

I tried a couple options at the bottom but can't figure it out.

I've done some searching about to find an answer but can't seem to get anything to work inside of what I have already.

Any help much appreciated.

```html
<div class="title">
  <div class="logo">
    <a id="logo-home" href="index.html">
      <img src="/Public/Images/light-image.png" class="light-theme-logo" style="width: 100%;">
      <img src="/Public/Images/dark-image.png" class="dark-theme-logo">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 80px;
  height: auto;
}

.light-theme-logo {
  display: block;
}

.dark-theme-logo {
  display: contents;
}
```

```js
const MOON = '';
const SUN = '☀️';
const DARK_MODE = 'dark';
const LIGHT_MODE = 'light';
const DEFAULT_MODE = LIGHT_MODE;

const btn = document.querySelector('#theme-switcher');

init();

function init() {
  let storedMode = sessionStorage.getItem('mode');
  if (!storedMode) {
    storedMode = DEFAULT_MODE;
    sessionStorage.setItem('mode', DEFAULT_MODE);
  }
  setMode(storedMode);
}

function setMode(mode = DEFAULT_MODE) {
  if (mode === DARK_MODE) {
    btn.textContent = SUN;
    document.body.classList.add(DARK_MODE);

  } else if (mode === LIGHT_MODE) {
    btn.textContent = MOON;
    document.body.classList.remove(DARK_MODE);

  }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let mode = sessionStorage.getItem('mode');
  if (mode) {
    let newMode = mode == DARK_MODE ? LIGHT_MODE : DARK_MODE;
    setMode(newMode);
    sessionStorage.setItem('mode', newMode);
  }
})

function setLogo(mode = DEFAULT_MODE) {
  if (mode === DARK_MODE) {
    btn.textContent = SUN;
    document.body.classList.add(DARK_LOGO);

  } else if (mode === LIGHT_MODE) {
    btn.textContent = MOON;
    document.body.classList.remove(DARK_LOGO);

  }
};

function logoSwap() {
  if (mode === LIGHT_MODE) {
    document.body.classList.add("Images/Light-Image.png");
  } else if (mode === DARK_MODE) {
    document.body.classList.remove("Images/Dark-Image.png");
  }

};
```

Comment: You are adding a class with the path of your image... Don't you mean to add some CSS class name that then determines the image inside it using some property? I don't believe this is a valid CSS class name. Anyway, we can't know all the details without your HTML and CSS, please add those to the question (only add the relevant stuff, not the entire HTML page)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @casraf Can I add in the image direct like in the above change? I'm not sure how to specify the image for change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out, and it was simpler than I was making it out to be.

```js
function setMode(mode = DEFAULT_MODE) {
if (mode === DARK_MODE) {
    btn.textContent = SUN;
    document.body.classList.add(DARK_MODE);
    document.getElementById("light-theme").src = "Images/Dark-Image.png";
    

} else if (mode === LIGHT_MODE) {
    btn.textContent = MOON;
    document.body.classList.remove(DARK_MODE);
    document.getElementById("light-theme").src = "Images/Light-Image.png";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of working with just HTML, No CSS or JS needed

```
<picture>
 <source
srcset="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/0f0f/fff"
   media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)"
   class="h-[45vh] object-cover"
   />
  <img
 src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/bebe/000"
   alt="desktop bg dark"
   class="h-[45vh] object-cover"          
 />
</picture>
```